# Java Loop through SQL Resultset and check objects are of different object types

Tags: java

I'm trying to iterate through a Resultset and add the objects to a ArrayList.
I have two different objects Player and Coach. I want them added to the same list.

I know you can use the instanceof to determine object type in a condition.
However I am unsure how you code it in regards to a resultset.

So how do you write a if statement for comparing a resultset object to a class?

```
                    String sql = "SELECT * FROM tblmember'" + ";";
            
                    
                    System.out.println("Before query");
                    r = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

                    ArrayList<Member> rlist = new ArrayList<>();
                                        
                    if ( r.next())
                    {
                    
                        while(r.next()) {
                                if row instanceof Player  //pseudocode needs to know this
                                {   
                                        rlist.add(new Player(r.getInt("fldmemberid"),(r.getString("fldfirstname"));
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                       rlist.add(new Coach(r.getInt("fldmemberid"),(r.getString("fldfirstname"));
                                }
                        
                        
                        }
```

Comment: Can you add the executed SQL statement and your table structure. There should be a discriminator column allowing to differentiate the mapped object type.

Comment: We don't know what `something` is either. Is there some field in the data that distinguishes Players from Coaches?

Comment: sorry ive edited it. I dont know how to write the if statement thats what i meant by "something". How do you iterate through a SQL resultset and if the row is a instanceof Player or else Coach - how to do code this

Comment: You could just cast it to Player and if it fails, cast it to Coach, although this is a very bad design. You either want a separate table for each type or like the previous comments said add a type column. Another option is to have both classes extend a parent class.

Comment: how would you do that ?

Comment: if (r.next() instanceof Player)

Comment: yes both classes (Player and Coach) do extend a parent class which is Member. But I cannot add objects to a list without giving them a type

Answer (score 1):

You cannot check if an item in `ResultSet` is an instance of your own classes, because it will never be. `ResultSet` is something that the JDBC library creates to hold the data, it does not know about your classes. You have to look at the data and determine which class, i.e. `Player` or `Coach` to instantiate yourself.

For example

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM tblmember"; 
try (ResultSet resultSet = stmt.executeQuery(sql)) {
    while (resultSet.next()) { 
        String memberType = resultSet.getString("member_type");
        if ("PLAYER".equals(memberType)) {
           rlist.add(new Player(r.getInt("fldmemberid"), (r.getString("fldfirstname"))
        } else if ("COACH".equals(memberType)) {
           rlist.add(new Coach(r.getInt("fldmemberid"),(r.getString("fldfirstname"));
        } else {
           throw new RuntimeException("Invalid member type: " + memberType);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: String memberType = resultSet.getString("member_type");  //doesnt this give you the column names data, and not the type of the object for that row. Therefore resultSet.getString will be getting data from column name "member_type". This wasn't what i was after. I need it to get the row (stored object) and then determines the type based on my classes

Comment: That will not be possible unless you are using some more advance library such as JPA, which automatically instantiate "the row (stored object)" as your desire (behind the scene, it will basically use the column like `member_type` to do the same as in my example). Or Spring JDBC template, which will have you to define how to map an item from the result set to your class. By the way `resultSet.getString("member_type")` does not give you the column name data, it gives the actual row data for the column `member_type`.